# How do I prevent my discord bot from freezing?

Tags: python, discord.py

My discord bot does exactly what it needs to do but for some reason it stops after a while.
The bot is still shown as online, but I cant use it or even use the command set to turn it off.
I cant tell if this is an issue outside the code, or theres something I need to put in so it doesnt "freeze".
I run the code within VS code which might be an issue, I tried running it within CMD and powershell but since I dont have a "main" function it doesnt want to run.

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
import asyncio

BOT_TOKEN = [almost doxxed myself lol]
CHANNEL_ID = [almost doxxed myself lol] 

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_message(message: discord.Message):
    if "https://twitter.com/" in message.content:
        new_message = message.content[:8] + "vx" + message.content[8:]
        await message.channel.send(new_message)
        await message.delete()
    await bot.process_commands(message)
@bot.event
async def on_message(message: discord.Message):
    if "https://x.com/" in message.content:
        new_message = message.content[:8] + "fixv" + message.content[8:]
        await message.channel.send(new_message)
        await message.delete()
    await bot.process_commands(message)
@bot.event
async def on_message(message: discord.Message):
    if "https://www.tiktok.com/t/ZT8QnN8hg/" in message.content:
        new_message = message.content[:8] + "vx" + message.content[8:]
        await message.channel.send(new_message)
        await message.delete()
    await bot.process_commands(message)
    
@bot.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def ss(context):
    exit()

bot.run(BOT_TOKEN)
```

I'm still learning a lot, especially since I dont know how to use Python that much in the first place. My thoughts are it could be a windows going to sleep issue, running it in VS code, or maybe the code gets "full" somehow after people use it to a certain point and it locks up.
Any help is appreciated and I'd really like to learn why this is the case, googling it didnt seem to help at all
Thanks in advance. <3

Comment: It might be from the three `@bot.event` `on_message` handlers. If you only make it one, does that fix the problem?

Comment: Why can't you run it in CMD? You don't need a main function to do that. You also don't need 3 `on_message` events, you can put all your code into a single one. Also, what is `exit()`? The function is not defined anywhere.